# Why "git reset <file>" returns 1?

Tags: git, return-value, git-reset

Assume that `foo.txt` is in the index.

Why doing:

```
git reset foo.txt
```

returns 1:

```
$ echo $?
1
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git reset foo.txt` returns zero when `foo.txt` has no unstaged changes after the reset, and one when it does.

This allows scripting code to determine if the file in question has been modified since the last commit.

Comment: Interestingly, when `foo.txt` has unstaged changes after the reset, and the `-q` option is used, it returns `0`.

Comment: @MishaMoroshko The `-q` flag instructs the command to only report errors, I suppose...